# User Interface for Katta Index

Tags: lucene, katta

I m developing a User interface for Katta Index. For that I need to find, the indexed field's names (and if possible its data type how it was indexed either normal string or Float or Int or long etc...) and number of documents the index contains....
--Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [katta documentation](http://katta.sourceforge.net/documentation/how-to-create-a-katta-index),

> ...a Katta index is basically just a folder with Lucene index sub folders...

So I would try to use [luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) to view the index structure.
I see this advice appears also under [common problems in katta](http://katta.sourceforge.net/documentation/common-problems).