# Katta luke integration

Tags: lucene, luke, katta

I m using Katta for distributed Lucene Index. Is it possible to use LUKE for Katta index, if so, how? Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [User Interface for Katta Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929634/user-interface-for-katta-index)

Comment: Surendhar, I already answered a very similar question you asked. I believe you need not ask this again. Also, it is considered common courtesy to accept answers which are useful.

Comment: but, i didn't get any IDEA, "http://katta.sourceforge.net/documentation/common-problems" they mentioned only for Lucene Index, not for Katta Index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fair enough. They basically say that a Katta index is a folder containing Lucene indexes. 
So what you need to do is:

1. Install Luke.
2. Point it at the sub-folders of the Katta index.
3. See what these indexes' structure is.